# Нужно ли создавать несколько пользователей для доступа к БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет. Уже как пол года пишу программу и сейчас задался вопросом. 
**Нужно ли создавать несколько пользователей базы данных?**
У меня в программе у каждого работника есть свой логин и пароль, они заходят и вбивают выполненную работу. Несколько человек одновременно.
Вопрос нужно ли для работников создавать отдельно пользователя? Или Вообще для каждого работника отдельно? Или пускай все работают под одним?

Я говорю про этих пользователей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Они прямо в БД работают, пишут SQL запросы?

Comment: Нет конечно)) у программы есть ui. Она сама отправляет готовые запросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, у каждого пользователя работающего в компании, который выполняет действия в базе данных должен быть свой аккаунт, т.к. можно разделять обязанности и условия доступа к базе данных и контролировать отключение доступа в случае наступления определенных событий.

Можно отследить кто выполняет неправильные запросы или запросы которые нагружают базу данных, отключить доступ, если человек уволился, временно прекратить доступ в случае отпуска, увидеть кто пытается слить всю вашу базу данных (если есть логирование). Какому-то аккаунту разрешить доступ с домашнего IP (как кейс, но это очень нежелательно, доступа к БД вообще не должно быть вне офиса и дата-центра).

В основном причины здесь связаны с информационной безопасностью и желательно соблюдать разделение аккаунтов. Мало компаний соблюдает данное правило, и множество пользователей работает под одним аккаунтом в офисе (а что, ведь доступ только из офиса), но так случается что утекает база данных вместе с увольнением кого-то и отследить кто это сделал в целом невозможно по причине одного аккаунта и отсутствия корректного логирования.

Как правильно заметил @gecube, все зависит от задач и если у Вас именно программа соединяется с сервером базы данных, то конечно можно работать через один логин, но будьте уверены, что ваш данные соединения скрыты от пользователя, но не от хакера и при правильных методах данные можно получить. Может у Вас в коллективе хакеров нет и никто этим заниматься не будет, но все может быть.

Правильное решение для подобных задач это клиент-серверное приложение работающее через определенное API (а API уже работает с базой) и выполняющие команды через написанную для API систему авторизации с системой логирования произведенных действий.

Ваше приложение просто неправильно использует ресурсы БД, 200 пользователей работающих с базой это 200 одновременных коннектов, тогда как на сервере можно держать пул соединений и выдавать данные по требованию.

Comment: У меня в самой программе для каждого работника свой логин и пароль! И сама программа не дает пользователю изменить или удалить записи, если ему это не положено. Прямого доступа к базе данных работники не будут иметь никак!

Если у меня 200 работников, то мне надо создать 200 пользователей в БД?

Comment: @АлександрРублев повторюсь что зависит от задач. Рассмотрите такой сценарий. Особо ушлый пользователь - взламывает Вашу программу, считывает оттуда логин и пароль для доступа к базе данных. Затем по сети подсоединяется к базе данных и убивает все ее содержимое. Чтобы этого избежать - да, нужно для каждого пользователя отдельно заводить учетку в самой системе базы данных.

Comment: Если же программа двухкомпонентная - скажем, клиентская часть общается с неким скриптом на веб-сервере, а он уже общается напрямую с базой данных - тут для каждой учетки пользователя не нужен дубликат в базе

Comment: Нет у меня клиентская часть -> БД

Comment: Мне казалось что правильно было бы под офисных работников выделить пользователя БД с ограниченными правами. Для мелких работников которые вбивают свою работу выделить пользователя БД которуму разрешено только SELECT и INSERT к единственной таблице. Так правильно будет?

Comment: @gecube все правильно сказал, про взлом и требований к задачам. В целом архитектура не совсем верная, логин к базе данных должен быть один и точка входа одна, а разграничение к операциям должно быть на уровне системы авторизации. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: @АлександрРублев у Вас доступ к БД будет только из офиса или приложение можно запустить где угодно? В нем есть своя система авторизации?

Comment: Только из офиса! Да есть своя система аторизации с ограничением прав доступа!

Comment: @АлександрРублев тогда можете работать из под одного пользователя и это логично, но учитывайте на будущее, что логин и пароль к базе храняться небезопасно, а еще при большом кол-ве пользователей и такой архитектуре у Вас будут проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: А как решать эти проблемы с производительностью?

Comment: @АлександрРублев видимо, нужно пересмотреть всю архитектуру. Для начала перейти на другую схему работы - перестать гонять голые SQL запросы по сети, а сделать трехуровневую модель ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ <---JSON или что-то подобное ---> WEB-сервер <-----> SQL

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Все зависит от задач. Ответ коллеги @Firepro абсолютно верен. Но хочу обратить внимание, что способов разделить права доступа достаточно много. Смотрите. Если все работники работают ЧЕРЕЗ ОДНУ программу с базой данных (т.е. одна точка входа), то допустимо, чтобы в этой программе логин и пароль для доступа к базе данных были зашиты внутри. Вот возьмите все современные CMS - у них логин-пароль для входа в базу данных ЕДИНЫЙ, а вот логины и пароли пользователей хранятся в БД. В CMS права доступа также назначаются на ресурсы (страницы) как некие поля в базе данных. При этом есть нюанс, что к базе данных СНАРУЖИ никаких соединений нет. Т.е. нельзя просто взять, украсть логин и пароль и прозвести с базой данных какие-либо вредоносные действия.

Еще подумайте о чем. Если у Вас несколько проектов на одном хосте, то для каждого из них ТОЧНО нужно иметь свой вход (пару логин-пароль) в базу данных. Но если есть пользователи для каждого из проектов и они пересекаются, то как Вы будете их заводить???

Comment: Проект один! Выше я оставил комментарий!